# react hooks didnt works

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so i got this method in a react function component

```
let req = () => {
    setLoading('fas fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-spinner')
    setQuestion('')
    setAnswer('')
    setTimer(2)     //set i here
    setChoices([])
    setDisplay('none')
    setdisplayTimer('none')
    fetch('https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1&category=9&type=boolean')
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data.results[0])
            let interval = setInterval(() => {
                setdisplayTimer('block')
                setTimer(timer--)     //substract i here
                if (timer < 0) {
                    clearInterval(interval)
                    setDisplay('block')
                }
            }, 1000);
            console.log(timer)
            setLoading('')
            setAnswer(data.results[0].correct_answer)
            setQuestion((data.results[0].question).replace(/&quot;/g, '"').replace(/&#039;s/g, "'s").replace(/&#34;/g, '"').replace(/&#039;t/, "'t").replace(/&#039;/, "'"))
            setChoices(['True', 'False'])
        })
}
```

previously i also declared `const [timer, setTimer] = useState(4)`

the problem is my hooks for `setTimer` is still 0 when i call the method for the second time eventough i already set it to initial value in the first place. thank you for any suggestion!

Comment: Which hook is still 0? Elaborate your question please.

Comment: you need to use useEffect() and/or preserve state

Comment: Which useEffect exactly?

Comment: I'm assuming `timer` is a state variable. Don't ever mutate a state variable, e.g. `timer--`

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

You have a stale `timer` state enclosure in the interval callback. Likely the initial state `timer: 0` is enclosed and the `setTimer(2)` has no effect on later `timer` value accesses since they used the closed over initial state value.

## Solution

Use a functional state update to update from the previous state and not the state the update was enqueued in.

```
setTimer(timer => timer - 1)
```

Comment: Well, that's one issue, but now the problem is knowing when to clear the interval, and to solve that, the timer logic really should be in a separate `useEffect`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Sure, there may be more optimal ways to clear the interval, but OP isn't asking about that. BTW, just tested this and the interval is cleared by the interval ref also closed over in the interval callback.

Comment: I think we might be talking about slightly different aspects of the question. If you use the functional state update, my implied question was what would be the revised condition for clearing the interval that you suggest with this approach?

Comment: thanks @DrewReese ! your answer help me. turns out i need to separate the interval method so then i just need to call it after fetch the data